# Variance estimation in a one-factor linear model

Tags: pca, multivariate-analysis, factor-analysis, covariance-matrix

I was given a dataset (a mat file) of $100\: 000$ observations, each with $50$ dimensions (coordinates). Denote matrix $X$ a $50\times 100\:000$ matrix in which each column was generated according to:

$$\mathbf x_i = a_i \mathbf u + \boldsymbol \epsilon_i,$$

where $\mathbf u \in \mathbb R^{50}$ is some fixed 50-dimensional vector, $\mathbf x_i$ is a $50$-dimensional vector with $i$ indexing observations ($i=1...100\:000$). Each $a_i$ is a scalar, $a_i \sim \mathcal N(0, \sigma_a)$ i.i.d Gaussian with zero mean and unknown finite variance. Noise term $\boldsymbol \epsilon_i$ is a 50-dimensional vector, with each coordinate $\epsilon_j \sim \mathcal N(0, \sigma_\epsilon)$ i.i.d. Gaussian with zero mean and unknown finite variance. We can assume that $a_i$ and $\boldsymbol \epsilon_i$ are independent.

**I need to estimate $\sigma_a$ (a scalar), $\sigma_\epsilon$ (a scalar) and $\mathbf u$ (a vector).**

---

### My attempts so far

Denote $\mathbf z_i=a_i \mathbf u$. Since $E[a_i^2]=\sigma_a^2$, the $p\times p$ covariance matrix of $\mathbf z$ is given by:

$$\Sigma=E[z_iz_i^T]=\mathbf u\mathbf u^T\sigma_a^2.$$

Then, the covariance matrix of $\mathbf x$ is given by
$$S=\mathbf u\mathbf u^T\sigma_a^2+\sigma_\epsilon^2\mathbf I_{p\times p}.$$

Since $n\gg p$ in my case, the sample covariance matrix $S_n$ converges to $S$. Hence, $\sigma_a^2$ (the variance of $a_i$) and the noise variance $\sigma_\epsilon^2$ can be estimated from the sample covariance matrix.

So, we computed $S$ and we have an equation of $S$ with $\mathbf u$, $\sigma_a$, and $\sigma_\epsilon$. **But I couldn't find a way to recover $\mathbf u$ and I feel like I'm missing something.**

I applied SVD and found the spectral decomposition of $X$, but couldn't figure out how the eigenvalues/eigenvectors can help me to estimate the variances $\sigma_a$ and $\sigma_\epsilon$ or to find $\mathbf u$.

Comment: It will be virtually impossible to provide a correct answer without knowing if $\epsilon_i$ and $\alpha_i$ are independent for each $i.$

Comment: We can assume they are independent

Comment: It would be best to tell us what your data really are and what you are trying to learn about them: it looks like essential information has been lost or corrupted in your effort to state your question abstractly.

Comment: Much better, thank you! Notice that your model does not change if you simultaneously change $u$ to $\lambda u$ and $\sigma_a$ to $\sigma_a/|\lambda|$ for some nonzero number $\lambda$, because that would not alter the distribution of $x_i$ at all. Therefore $\sigma_a$ is not identifiable and only the *direction* of $u$ is identifiable, but not its magnitude. If you were to constrain $u$--insist it's a unit vector, for instance--then almost everything would be identifiable; the only remaining ambiguity would be that both $u$ and $-u$ would work as solutions.

Comment: @whuber thank you for the help and good will! I re-added the post with all I know about the given data and problem definition.

Comment: That's the whole point: $\lambda$ could be *anything.* You simply don't know. Consider a hugely simplified version of this model: you observe a number $x$ and assume it is equal to $\alpha u$ where $\alpha\sim\text{Normal}(0,\sigma^2)$ and $u$ is unknown. You are basically trying to write $x$ as the product of two numbers.  There are infinitely many ways to do that and all are equally good from the point of view of your model.  Mathematically this is proven by noting $\alpha u = (\alpha/\lambda)(\lambda u)$.

Comment: @amoeba For the noise, each coordinate is Gaussian iid with zero mean and some unknown (fixed) variance.

Comment: OK, now I am happy with the question, it became nice and clear :) +1 I think I can answer it, but will only have the time later today. Consider erasing your comments that became obsolete (I have erased mine).

Comment: I wonder who downvoted this and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, @whuber is right: your $\sigma_a^2$ and $\newcommand{\u}{\mathbf u}\u$ are underdetermined: as you computed yourself, they enter the covariance matrix as a $\u\u^\top\sigma^2_a$ term, and so if you e.g. multiply $\u$ by two and divide $\sigma_a$ by two, this term will not change. Therefore you should either fix the length of $\u$ or the value of $\sigma_a$. Let's fix $$\sigma_a=1.$$

Second, let's rewrite your formula in a somewhat more standard notation. We have: $$a \sim \mathcal N(0,1) \\\mathbf x =a\u+\boldsymbol \epsilon \sim \mathcal N (a\u, \sigma^2_\epsilon \mathbf I).$$ It is a probabilistic model that is almost *factor analysis* with a single factor $a$. It would be exactly factor analysis, if you had an arbitrary diagonal covariance of $\boldsymbol \epsilon$, i.e. if different components of $\boldsymbol \epsilon$ were allowed to have different variances. Factor analysis model with one factor can be fit e.g. via expectation-maximization (and there are standard routines for that). Vector $\u$ is called a vector of *loadings*.

If your noise covariance matrix is not only diagonal, but also isotropic, i.e. $\sigma^2_\epsilon \mathbf I$, then factor analysis reduces to *probabilistic PCA (pPCA)*. It can also be fit via expectation-maximization, however it turns out that there is an analytical maximum likelihood solution (unlike for FA). The solution is as follows:

\begin{align}\sigma_\epsilon^2 &= \frac{1}{p-1}\sum_{i=2}^p \lambda_i \\ \u &= \mathbf w_1 (\lambda_1 - \sigma_\epsilon^2)^{1/2},\end{align}

where $\mathbf w_1$ and $\lambda_1$ are the first eigenvector  of the observed covariance matrix $\mathbf S$ and its eigenvalue, and $\lambda_i$ -- other eigenvalues.

I think this is what you need. Note that $\u$ is pointing in the direction of the first principal axis and is almost equal to the PCA loading vector $\lambda_1 \mathbf w_1$, but compared to it is slightly scaled down in length to "make room" for the noise covariance.